# Plot 3d scattered data using gnuplot

Tags: bash, command, ubuntu-12.04, gnuplot

Hi I just got some 3d scattered data (the data name is just `data.txt`) which look like the following:

```
0 0 0 
-1.08051e-16 -1.73991e-16 -1.79157e-16 
-1.02169e-15 -1.19283e-15 5.92632e-16 
3.41114e-16 -1.02211e-15 3.19436e-15 
-4.51742e-15 -5.18861e-15 -4.60754e-15 
-2.00685e-15 -4.67813e-15 -4.86101e-15 
-9.82727e-16 -2.24413e-15 -5.87927e-16 
-7.74439e-16 -9.73515e-16 -1.69707e-15 
4.32668e-16 2.15869e-15 -2.25004e-15 
-3.74495e-15 -2.20596e-15 -7.33201e-16 
-4.97941e-16 -5.45749e-16 -2.93136e-15 
-2.40174e-15 -4.31022e-15 7.13531e-15 
-4.58812e-15 -4.38568e-15 -9.99635e-16 
-7.00716e-15 7.53852e-15 -8.484e-15 
4.50028e-15 2.2255e-15 2.32808e-15 
-8.57887e-15 3.09127e-15 -3.49207e-15 
-2.0608e-16 -6.06078e-15 -6.07822e-16 
-7.76829e-15 -1.47001e-14 -1.08924e-14 
1.04016e-15 6.33122e-16 -2.11985e-15 
2.33557e-15 -7.92667e-15 2.52748e-15 
6.94335e-15 3.70286e-15 -1.44815e-15
.........
```

the 1st,2nd and 3rd column represent x,y and z axis, respectively.
I'd like to use splot command to plot these data. Can anyone kindly give some suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is nicely formatted, you could start with

```
splot 'data.txt'
```

If you want to get fancy, you can add some options to change how it is plotted:

```
splot 'data.txt' with points pointtype 7
```

What kind of suggestions are you looking for?